# Migration from gitlap to tuleap?

Tags: gitlab, tuleap

Currently our company uses gitlab for repository management and issue management.

Is there a tool or an easy way to migrate (Issues, files, wiki, etc....) from gitlab to tuleap ?

Or any guides how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Dev team speaking.

There is a lot of work on going on import/export means for Tuleap but no automated stuff from gitlab right now. However, the import format is documented (would covers Issues and git ATM) so you can write your own:
https://docs.tuleap.org/administration-guide/projects-management/project-export-import.html#import-format